# how to show that $f_n$ is nonnegative on an open interval for all $n$ large enough

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of continous functions on $[0,1]$ and for all $x\in [0,1], f_n(x)$ is eventually nonnegative. Show that there is an open interval $I\subseteq[0,1]$ such that for all $n$ large enough, $f_n$ is nonnegative everywhere on $I$.

Here is my try: $$\{ x\in [0,1]: \liminf f_n(x)>0\}=I=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{k=n}^\infty\{x\in [0,1]:f_k(x)>0\}.$$So there exist $n_0$ st $\mu \{\cap_{k=n_0}^\infty\{x\in [0,1]:f_k(x)>0\}\}>0$, but how to show it contains an interval?

Comment: It must be $\geqslant 0$ rather than $> 0$, and it's not about measure, but about Baire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F_n = \{x \in [0,1] : f_m(x) \ge 0$ $ \forall m \ge n\} = \cap_{m = n}^\infty\{x \in [0,1]:f_m(x) \ge 0\}$. Then $F_n$ is closed for all $n$ by the continuity of $f_n$, and $[0,1]$ = $\displaystyle \cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$

Now use the Baire Category Theorem.